# Issue with a formal notation.

Tags: notation, systems-of-equations

I was thinking how to formally express a set of the following property.
First of all we have got a set of $i\in\{a,b,c,...\}$. Then we want to consider equations of an arbitrary form (say: $x_i\leq i'$), in which $i$ is included. However, we want these equations to exist only if a variable directly connected with $i$, call it $i'$ meets a certain condition (say: $i'>2$).

For example, we have got a set $i\in\{a,b,c\}$ and we know that $a'=3$, $b'=0$, $c'=6$. So that we will have the inequalities:
$$x_a\leq 3$$
$$x_c\leq 6$$
(We don't want to have equation for $x_b$ as the condition $b'>2$ is not met.)

How to write it formally?

I have got an idea, however, I am not sure whether it captures the described abouve behaviour.
$$x_i\leq i'$$ $$where:$$ $$i\in\{k\in\{a,b,c,...\}|k'>2\}$$

What do you think about it?

Answer (score 0):

How about expressing your conditional values as another subscripted variable instead of a prime on the index?

"Let $A = \{a, b, c, ...\}$ and suppose that $x_i \le y_i$, for all $i \in A$ such that $y_i > 2$."

Comment: Thank you Paul. Problem is that the whole thing has to be expressed as a set (these inequalities go into a linear problem). Have you got any idea how to express your suggestion as a set? i.e. $x\in A$, where A contains this condition.

Comment: Before I can answer that, you need to be *considerably* clearer about what you are after than you have so far attempted to be.  What you do mean by "the whole thing has to be expressed as a set"? What is it that is supposed to be in this set? the various values $x_i$? or maybe a set of indexed collections of {x_i} that satisfies the conditions? or what? So far you have been very unclear, and I have tried to grasp some sense of what you are talking about out of it. But you want help, you are going to have to be more specific.

Comment: Okay, I will try. I have also expressed my conditional values as another subscripted variable ($w_i$) instead of a prime on an index. Please look at this. $x_{i_k} \in \{0,1\}, i_k\in\Big\{h_t: h\in\big\{r\in\{1,...,m\}|w_r>2\big\} \wedge t\in \{2,...,w_h\}\Big\}$ What I want to express is that $x_{i_k} \in \{0,1\}$ holds for all $i_k$ but only when $w_i$ is grater than 2. Then if $w_i$ is greater than 2, the equation holds for all $k$ (for this particular $i$) between 2 and $w_i$. Is is clear now? I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: No it isn't. Usually subscripts indicate the value of the main variable is a function of the subscript, but that interpretation makes no sense with how you are using and describing $i_k$ and $h_t$. Do you perhaps mean that $i$ and $k$ are separate indices that both need specified? If so, then use $(i, k)$, not $i_k$.

Comment: I will try to put it in other words. At the beginning I had $x_{i_k}\in\{0,1\}$ for all $i\in\{1,...,m\}$ and $k\in\{2,...,w_i\}$ for each $i$. But the thing is that it may actually happen that for some $i$, $w_i$ is equal to for example $1$. Then for that particular $i$, we have: $x_{i_k}\in\{0,1\}$ for all $k\in\{2,...,w_i=1\}$. So there are no equations at all for this $i$ as set $\{2,...,1\}$ has no meaning. This is exactly what I am trying to avoid, Do you see what I am trying to do?

Comment: You tell me what $i$ is in, but you don't use $i$, you use $i_k$. What is $i_k$ in? what is the relationship between $i$ and $k$. The way you phrase it, it sounds like you want multiple values of $i_k$ for the same value of $k$, which is a definite misuse of subscript notation. So could you please put in some words to address this question, which I also asked last time?